# Sampling theory and frequency spacing

Tags: fft, sampling, nyquist

If a CT signal $x(t)$ is sampled for one ($1$) second and $4096$ samples are generated:

1. Isn't the highest frequency that can be sampled without aliasing ($4096/2$) $2048\textrm{ Hz}$?
2. If a $4096$ FFT of this signal is computed what is the frequency spacing between the output points (in $\textrm{Hz}$) ?

Comment: The highest frequency that can sampled without aliasing is below (not at) SR/2.  For strictly real input data, half of the DFT result bins are just a redundant congregate mirror image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the highest frequency is half the sampling rate. The frequency spacing is 1 Hz since samples are accumulated for 1 second.